# Bayes estimate of mixture of exponential under the the Kullback-Leibler divergence loss function

Tags: bayesian, estimation, loss-functions, kullback-leibler, mixture-distribution

Model framework:

Suppose that the loss function is given by the Kullback-Leibler divergence (KLD) as follows:

\begin{equation}
\text{KL}(\Theta \parallel \hat{\Theta}) = \text{KL}\big(f(x;\Theta) \parallel f(x; \hat{\Theta})\big) = \int_{\mathcal{A}}\log\frac{f(x; \Theta)}{f(x; \hat{\Theta})}f(x; \Theta) dx, 
\end{equation}

The Bayes estimate is then defined

\begin{eqnarray}
\Theta^B = \text{arg}\min_{\hat{\Theta}}\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\text{KL}(\Theta \parallel \hat{\Theta})\Big| \mathbf{x}]
\end{eqnarray}

Now, assume that the random variable $X$ follows a mixture of two exponential distributions which is given by:

\begin{equation}
f(x; \Theta)  = \phi \alpha e^{-\alpha x} + (1-\phi) \beta e^{-\beta x}
\end{equation}

Is it possible to come up with a close form expression for the Bayse estimate of parameters under the above framework? If not, what would be a solution, maybe numerical methods?

Comment: Are you looking for estimators of all three of $\alpha, \beta,\phi$?

Comment: yes, all parameters. In fact, we have $\Theta = (\phi, \alpha, \beta)$.

Comment: There is no closed form expression for the KLD in this setting.

Comment: so, what can I do? For example, applying the EM algorithm can be useful? Suppose that we can generate a sample from their posterior distributions, then if it is possible to solve the above minimization problem via the EM algorithm?